# How to turn off warnings, 'ruby -w', in 'rake test'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have inherited a huge Rails project with hundreds of warnings, due to other people's sloppy coding habits, none of which I can fix.

When I run an individual test suite, with `ruby test/function/my_controller_test.rb`, I get a clean run with no warnings. But when I run `rake test`, something deep in Rails's rake tasks turns on `ruby -w`, activating Ruby's warning system. How do I deactivate that line? I will edit the source and erase the `-w` if I must, but where is it?

The answer is not `rake -q` - that turns off rake's own spew.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to suppress this you can add this to your shell config if you're using a POSIX-type shell:

```
export RUBYOPT=-W0
```

Or you can prepend that to any command:

```
RUBYOPT=-W0 ruby ...
```

For other shells you'll need to set that environment variable somehow.

Answer (score 8):

I'm sure this has long been resolved, but for any future folks finding this, there is a clean way to do with with in the rakefile. Just add `t.warning = false` to your raketask config. So for example, a super generic one would be:

```
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.test_files = FileList['source_code/*_test.rb']
  t.verbose = true
  t.warning = false 
end
```

Fixing the warnings is still the best solution, but if needed, here ya go :)

Comment: thanks! at least this is now documented somewhere. But I can't upvote it because I'm not working on a Rake project right now! C-;